# Facings issues in fetching Multiple users Subscription for Presence MS Graph API (For Microsoft Teams)

Tags: angular, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, user-presence

I am using MS Graph API for fetching the user's presences, now i am stuck at fetching multiple subscriptions. e.g. If i have 10 users in my teams tenant, i want to get subscriptions for their presences, so that when someone's presence changed i will get a subscription. The method i am using is working fine for single user. When i give single user id in resources, subscription works fine but for multiple users, am unable to use the filter clause which mentioned in many documents.
Now now i need to add "/communications/presences?$filter=id in ({id},{id}…) (multiple users)" but am confused as it gives me invalid filter clause error if i add filter('') in it.

[below code is working for single user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MY1Ah.png)

Answer (score 0):

public getMSTeamsSubscriptionForPresence(ids) {
try {
let obj =
{
"changeType": "Updated",
"userid": this.configService.getCustomerID,
"expirationDateTime": "2021-12-22T10:45:39.2257768+00:00",
"resource": "/communications/presences?$filter=id in (" + ids + ")",
"notificationUrl": this.configService.apiUrl + "/teams",
}
return this.graphClient.api("/Subscriptions").post(obj);
// }
}
catch (err) {
console.log('error while getting subscription ', err);
}
}

where ids format will be 'id1','id2' etc.

Comment: Detail explanation is required.

Comment: At which stage you are stuck in, Please explain and i will provide details for it thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You check the filter documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters?context=graph%2Fapi%2Fbeta&view=graph-rest-beta#filter-parameter.
You'll see that values actually need to have '  ' around them.

So if you change your request to the following it should work:

```
{ 
  "changeType": "updated", 
  "notificationUrl": "https://c3b9ebcxxxxx.ngrok.io/presence-notify/", 
  "resource": "/communications/presences?$filter=id in ('a3c710b2-33f8-4e7c-85b9-cbd88cdbxxxx','eab3e87b-473d-4d2d-9587-b7156b7exxxx')",
  "expirationDateTime": "2021-12-30T08:37:12Z", 
  "clientState": "secretClientState" 
}
```

Comment: its already working now, i got it fixed. Now only issue am having is communications/getPresencesbyId returns wrong data. While this (this.graphClient.api('users/' + this.PresenceIDs[i] + '/presence').get(); ) returns fine data but it needs a loop and get info one by one which is time taking.

Comment: Please have a look at this doc- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/cloudcommunications-getpresencesbyuserid?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request
Let us know if you have any query.

Comment: am using the same API in above link for javascript.

Comment: as you mention above  'communications/getPresencesbyId' but in document it's "/communications/getPresencesByUserId".can you check it once.

Comment: sorry it was typo, communications/getPresencesByUserId works fine but gives response with invalid states like i am online but it will show offline, means it returns wrong data.

Comment: We tried to repro this issue from our end, we are getting proper data.
Could you please share steps you followed so that we can repro it at our end.

Comment: let status = await this.graphClient.api('/communications/getPresencesByUserId').post(presences);
  where in presences format is [ids: ['TeamsUserID1', 'TeamsUserID2']].

Comment: It gives wrong states. Hamzay449@gmail.com is my email, i can share you screenshots of response of getPresenceAPI.

Comment: Could you please try with the following Graph API. check once here also getting wrong status or not.

POST :-  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/getPresencesByUserId
Content-Type: application/json
{
 "ids": ["fa8bf3dc-eca7-46b7-bad1-db199xxxxxx", "66825e03-7ef5-42da-9069-724602xxxxx"]
}

Ref doc:-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/cloudcommunications-getpresencesbyuserid?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#examples

Comment: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/getPresencesByUserId. When i call in this way, it gives me correct results but with Graph Client, it gives wrong data. Only this API creating issues with Graph Client. As tokens thing is handled by Graph Client. What you suggest to overcome this issue, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Same ULR is going in network tab(https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/getPresencesByUserId), when i hit the getPresencesByUserId API.

Comment: we are checked with multiple devices. if one user can login with multiple device and set the different status.in that case it will also reflected with correct status using the above API. 
Ref doc:-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/cloudcommunications-getpresencesbyuserid?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#examples

Comment: Graph Client still gives me wrong data on /communications/getPresencesByUserId. Can we have a quick session?

Comment: @HAMZA - Could you please explain your scenario and steps you are trying, so that we can follow the same & check it once from our end?